# Bars of chart.js not appear

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, chart.js

[image]

The current effect is as above.

My code is as follows:

```js
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Bar
            data={this.traffic_chart}
            options={{
              responsive: true,
              scales: {
                x: {
                  stacked: true
                },
                y: {
                  stacked: true
                }
              },
              plugins: {
                title: {
                  display: true,
                  text: "the current traffic change based on the 30 day internet trends data point",
                  fontSize: 20
                },
                legend: {
                  display: true,
                  position: "right"
                }
              }
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
```

this.traffic_chart: (Bars don't appear whether I commented borderColor and borderWidth or not)

```js
this.traffic_chart = {
      labels: [],
      datasets: [{
        label: "Total",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)",
        //borderColor: "rgba(19,89,64,1)",
        //borderWidth: 2,
        data: []
      }, {
        label: "Http",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(53, 162, 235, 0.5)",
        //borderColor: "rgba(19,53,65,1)",
        //borderWidth: 2,
        data: []
      }]
    }
```

I filled the data in componentsDidMount() and I printed out to console, which looked like this:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: The chart rendering will not update dynamically so you likely need to conditionally render it based on the data's existence. Create a state variable called `ready` that defaults to `false` and update it to `true` in your `componentsDidMount` function after updating `this.traffic_chart`. Wrap the `Bar` render in a conditional that only returns if `ready` is `true`. Something like `{ready && <Bar ... />}`.

Comment: @TestWell Thank you, but I load `labels` in `componentsDidMount` too, why do they appear?

Comment: can you share componentsDidMount() content?